# How to execute function synchronously in ThreadPool?

Tags: c#, synchronization

I have a `Dictionary<string, Queue<Action>>`, This dict will add data dynamicly depending on there is new data in database or not.
Now the data in `Dictionary<string, Queue<Action>>` is like below:

```
"1",{A1,A2,A3,A4}
"2",{B1,B2,B3}
"3",{C1,C2}
```

my program will check this dictionary every 10 seconds and do Dequeue action from the dictionary and then do Invoke action. the execute role is like below:

1. A1,B1,C1 will execute first.
2. if A1 finishes, then start to execute A2; if B1 finishes, then start to execute B2;if C1 finishes, then start to execute C2; they don't need to wait for another one's completion.

now my code is like below:

```
 //This function is to add new data into dictionary if data comes
 private void DoComparison(StuffEntity entity)
    {
        try
        {
            bool dataFlag = CheckIsNewData(entity.PickingTime, entity.WarningPeriod);
            if (dataFlag)  
            {
                Action action = () => { DelaySendingMessageOut(entity); };
                if (!QueueItem.ContainsKey(entity.FridgeID))
                {
                    Queue<Action> queue = new Queue<Action>();
                    queue.Enqueue(action);
                    QueueItem.Add(entity.FridgeID, queue);
                }
                else
                {
                    QueueItem[entity.FridgeID].Enqueue(action);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CommonUnity.WriteLog(ex.Message);
            CommonUnity.WriteLog(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }


  //This function is to check the Dictionary
  //And this function will be checked every 10 seconds.
    private void CheckingQueue()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Queue<Action>> kvp in QueueItem)
        {
            string fridgeID = kvp.Key;
            Queue<Action> queue = kvp.Value;

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((_) =>
            {
                if (queue.Count > 0)
                {
                   //How can I know that the previous work has been finished?
                    queue.Dequeue().Invoke();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

[image]

Thx.
For this, I have a solution, create 3 threads and using AutoResetEvent array to sync Queue executation. but it will not be a good idea if there are thousands of items in the dict.

this is the code for DelaySendingMessageOut function:

```
private void DelaySendingMessageOut(StuffEntity entity)
    {
        int pendingPeroid = entity.PendingTime.ToInt();
        if (pendingPeroid <= 0)
            pendingPeroid = 5; 

        Thread.Sleep(pendingPeroid * 60 * 1000); //delay sending

        TriggerCheckingBeforeSendMessageOut(entity);
    }
```

Comment: The ThreadPool was the wrong choice for this, don't expect a small fix.

Comment: I've read the question twice and still can't understand, how it is related to synchronous execution of something in thread pool.

Comment: Do you want to wait if previous has not completed yet? or??

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes, I want. I want to sync Queue<Action>

Comment: @Dennis I don't know if threadpool is a good choice because for the items in Dictionary, I want them to run together, I only want to do is  syncing the Queue.

Comment: @Dennis img attached.

Comment: So basically you want A1,B1,C1 to execute in parallel but not A1,A2... ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes,correct.

Comment: Simply change your `if` to `while`, everything should work fine `while(queue.Count > 0)` :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel  I used "while" at first. my main thread will invoke CheckingQueue() function every 10 seconds. that didn't work for me .

Comment: Explain why that won't work for you?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I have attached DelaySendingMessageOut function, this function is the one which will be executed when dequeue. everything put in threadpool can't be managed by you. it will give a new thread to the function everytime you throw it into the threadpool.

Comment: So you're concerned about `Thread.Sleep` thing? what framework version you're in? Consider using `await Task.Delay(..)` or change the logic to `Tasks` and use `ContinueWith`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel  I used .net framework 4.0, thx for your advice, I will try Task

Comment: If you're interested in `async` consider using [Async Pack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel  got't